How to deal with a co-author that refuses to read a manuscript?
I finished a postdoc and then moved to a different position.  At the time of leaving I had a manuscript finished and ready to submit to a good journal.  I have two co-authors on the manuscript, one of them was my supervisor (who I did not get on well with) and the other was another postdoc of the supervisor (first author).  The supervisor contributed nothing in terms of ideas or work and is on the article because the first author likes to put his supervisor on everything.
Since we did not get on well, I guessed that the supervisor would not read the article to approve it for submission and would keep promising to read it and then never actually read it.  This seems to be what has happened.  I spoke to them in May before leaving and they said they would read it, but nothing happened.
20th July I received a message from my co-author that the supervisor would read it (nothing has happened).
5th September I received a message from the co-author saying he was waiting for the supervisor to look at the manuscript (still nothing has happened).
What can be done about this?  At what point is the length of time so long that I can contact the university asking them to tell him to read the manuscript or remove himself as an author if he does not wish to read it (having contributed nothing else)?  Obviously I put effort into this article and it has a high chance of getting into this journal so I don't want to walk away and forget about it.
Edit: I have spoken to the lead author and he will ask the supervisor if he is happy not to be a formal co-author on the paper, sounds promising.
Edit 2: The lead author will be having a follow-up discussion to see if he can get confirmation.
Edit 3: The lead author has now also left that university and so is only in sporadic communication with the supervisor, who has promised yet again to read the manuscript.  The saga continues.

The short answer is "never."

I think what you are experiencing now is the fallout of a broken relationship with your advisor. It might just be time to move on and cut your losses. You cannot force them to do anything, especially since you are not even the first author.

Does the first author have a good realationship with the supervisor? If so, perhaps they could take it up with them, and you could try to stay back to avoid inflaming things

I believe the first author has a good relationship so that might be the best route.

Couldn't you just write an email like "If I hear nothing from you within four weeks, I will hand in the manuscript as it is now." ?

@JFabianMeier Yes could do that.  It sounds a bit like a threat, but I will say something like that.

"contact the university asking them to tell him to read the manuscript" This isn’t how this works. Though it would be interesting to know what would happened if someone tried to do it anyway.

OK understood.  I suspect that if I tried it they would say they are unable to resolve authorship disputes or something like that.

If you have a timely need for the submission, you can say that in an email to the co-author(s). But if there is nothing really pressing, you could also just let it go.
While it might cause difficulties, it would shake the tree a bit if you suggest to both co-authors that the paper should be submitted by some date certain if there are no objections. Make the date a couple of weeks or so in the future.
The PI doesn't need to read the paper, but their permission to publish is needed. Those aren't the same.

"The PI doesn't need to read the paper, but their permission to publish is needed. Those aren't the same." Certainly true. It might take some diplomatic skills to go this way, though.

Unless one brings valuable, unique genius to the party, diplomacy is a great skill to develop.

From experience I think the PI reading the paper will be necessary, he will not give permission to publish without reading it.

The journal is a decent journal but the article is not essential to my career, walking away from it would not cause me any damage probably.  I would rather keep the article though.

Would it be possible to just remove the supervisor and publish it that way? Or is it unacceptable to the other (true) author?

I think the problem is that the (true) author puts his supervisor on every paper, even when the supervisor genuinely contributed nothing in this case.  I can ask him about the possibility of (a) submitting with the permission of the PI even if he has not read it or (b) or removing the PI from the paper, I think one of the two possibilities has to work somehow.

@Tom depending on the field, this can be entirely reasonable. For example, in biology, the PI is always listed as the last author. Even in the rare case where they contributed nothing to the specific paper, they still provided guidance, materials, reagents, a laboratory etc.

+1 especially for the middle paragraph. If soneone isn't communicating, inform them that (they've got another chance but) their silence will be taken for permission.

@GregMartin: This does not always work. I had once done it with my noncommunicative collaborator. The end-result was that my collaborator "blew his lid," and it resulted in a 3-4 year (!) delay in  publication of three joint papers.

@MoisheKohan Looking back now, do you think there was a better alternative?

@Mentalist: Yes, I should have been more patient... Eventualy, we started to collaborate again and wrote 9 more papers.
